# Disable buttons inside ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I disable all the buttons inside ng-repeat?
Here's my code..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array"> {{item.name}}<button type="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Submit</button></div>
```

Comment: `ng-disabled="true"`

Comment: `isDisabled` is a property of item?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some more information like on what basis you want to disable buttons any condition for that?

Comment: isDisabled is not a property in item array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If isDisabled is a property of the items in the array use:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array"> {{item.name}}<button type="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="item.isDisabled">Submit</button></div>
```

Comment: item.isDisabled is not a property of the items

Answer (score 3):

Just write `ng-disabled = "true"` in function where u want to disable your button